# Add focus style to div dynamically from css

Tags: jquery, html, css, focus

I am having a textboxleft side and and icon(div) on right side in dialog.
When I am opeing a dialog, both should be focused.

HTML

```
<input id="text-link" class="form-control" onfocus="this.select();" onclick="this.select();"/>
            <div class="form-control" id="link"></div>
```

I tried the below

```
1. $("#link").focus();
2. document.getElementById("link")
```

But not working.

Please suggest a css styling for dynamically adding focus to that div.

Comment: what you trying to achieve exactly

Comment: you want to focus on textbox on click of icon??

Comment: Need to focus that div while clicking on textbox and initially opeing the dialog.

Comment: where is the code for dialog?? and how to focus on  div while clicking on text box?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

JQUERY:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#link").removeClass("focusdiv");
    $("#text-link").focus(function(){
       $("#link").addClass("focusdiv");
    });
 });
```

CSS:

```
 .focusdiv{
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 5px 1px #eee; // Put box-shadow as your need.
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 5px 1px #eee;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 5px 1px #eee;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
 }
```